# Jenkins - How to pass environmental variable from freestyle job to pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a freestyle job in `Jenkins` and would normally pass parameters to another freestyle job using the Predefined parameters option. 
example:

```
PROJECT=Myproject
PATH=/depot/workspace/
```

Previously I could access the above values through the KEY in the downstream job through the environment by using `${PROJECT} OR ${PATH}`.

My problem now is that I have a pipeline job that needs to access the above values but when using `${PROJECT} OR ${PATH}` it does not work.

So, in general how I want it to work is have the freestyle job run first and pass the parameters to the downstream pipeline job.

Comment: Try with `"${params.PROJECT}"` in your pipeline.

Comment: @Dibakar Aditya Thanks. When I echo the "${params.PROJECT}" it can be seen in the console; however, in the pipeline script I am trying to use this value in a shell script and it unfortunately does not work. I am getting an error that says " script.sh: Bad substitution".

Comment: I figured it out. I had to use sh """#!/bin/bash echo \"${params.PROJECT}\" """.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use `"${params.PROJECT}"` in your pipeline to access the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your help.